# How to take the incremental data backup of a table in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Please explain with an example of incremental backup in BigQuery.

Example: I have a table name called `TEST_TABLE`.

- Day 1: full backup (means exported to Cloud storage): at 10 am EST I have inserted 10 records and on same day 10 PM EST I took the full backup of `TEST_TABLE` which has 10 rows.
- Day 2: 10 am EST I have inserted 20 rows into `TEST_TABLE`, now I want to take the incremental backup of newly inserted 20 rows only at 10 PM EST.

Thank you,
Abbas

Comment: Is your goal to append the 20 newly inserted records to the file that already exists in GCS?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not well defined but if you want to take a simple approach you can define a partition field on your table and each day select to your Google storage the latest partition. 
This will make sure you add new data for your backup store BUT will not handle updatea of historical partitions.

Comment: My question is how to do the increametal backup in BigQuery. Either in dataset level or table level or both.

Comment: There is no backup on dataset level, I suggest you check the partition option such as: `SELECT * FROM \`Project.dataset.table\` 
            WHERE 
            _PARTITIONTIME >= "2018-11-26 00:00:00" AND _PARTITIONTIME <= "2018-11-26 00:00:00"`